# How to handle duplicated manual mock found in the project

Tags: jestjs

The project has both client app and server site code and once the project is built locally it will put all the built assets both front-end and back-end stuff into `build` directory and it contains all statics assets client needs to use (all test cases are also included there).

When running the subsequent tests Jest will raise a warning message like below due to duplicated manual mock are existing in multiple directories.

```
jest-haste-map: duplicate manual mock found:
  Module name: fileMock
  Duplicate Mock path: /Users/x/x/x/x/src/resources/webapp/static/__mocks__/fileMock.js
This warning is caused by two manual mock files with the same file name.
Jest will use the mock file found in:
/Users/x/x/x/x/src/resources/webapp/static/__mocks__/fileMock.js
 Please delete one of the following two files:
 /Users/x/x/x/x/build/classes/webapp/static/__mocks__/fileMock.js
/Users/x/x/x/x/src/resources/webapp/static/__mocks__/fileMock.js
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Put `"<rootDir>/build"` inside `modulePathIgnorePatterns`, the `rootDir` is not a placeholder but a special token Jest can recognise, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#rootdir-string

Note that the `<rootDir>` is NOT a placeholder but a special token Jest uses to identifier the root of your project directory.

```
    "jest": {
        "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
            "<rootDir>/build"
        ]
    }
```

Add the `build` folder into `modulePathIgnorePatterns` inside your `package.json` file.

Comment: Also useful to know:  `"modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
  ".*__mocks__.*"
 ]` assuming you dont use this mock assumption pattern in your project.

Comment: what is the rootDir here ?

Comment: @AliYarKhan that's not a placeholder, it's a special token that will be understood by jest as your project root: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#rootdir-string

Comment: trying this solution I get this error: These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

  • modulePathIgnorePatterns

Answer (score 6):

If the duplicate is because of the same mocks, put the following in your `package.json` file:

```
  "jest": {
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      ".*__mocks__.*"
    ]
  }
```

You can find more info about this config option in [Configuring Jest here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulepathignorepatterns-arraystring).

Thanks to @Denis in the comments above.

Answer (score 3):

What helped for me was to set `roots` property. Made test finding much faster.

This is the link from docs
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#roots-arraystring

Answer (score 0):

I use Typescript and had the following warnings:

```js
jest-haste-map: duplicate manual mock found: createDocumentInput
  The following files share their name; please delete one of them:
    * <rootDir>/dist/modules/__mocks__/xxx.js
    * <rootDir>/src/modules/__mocks__/yyy.ts
```

I added the following  "exclusions"to the `tsconfig.json` and warnings dissapiared:

```
{
...
"exclude": [
    "dist",
    "**/__mocks__/*",
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "build",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```